# gstreamer: play audio file backwards in

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer, playback

I want to play audio files with different playback rates using *GStreamer*.  This already works fine.  However, in contrast to the [Python GStreamer reference](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-reference/class-gstevent.html#function-gstevent--event-new-seek), negative rates do **not** play the audio file backwards.

Does anybody know how to accomplish my goal?  Has this something to do with *filesrc* or *decodebin2* not being able to buffer the file for playing in reverse?  Or is this simply a bug?

Here's a (veeery) simplified version of my code:

```
import os

import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst
import gtk


gst_command = ('filesrc location=%s ! decodebin2 ! autoaudiosink') % \
    '/mnt/audio/test.wav'
pipeline = gst.parse_launch(gst_command)
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
pipeline.get_state()

position = 10 * gst.SECOND
rate = -1.0
pipeline.seek(rate, gst.FORMAT_TIME, \
           gst.SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | gst.SEEK_FLAG_ACCURATE, \
           gst.SEEK_TYPE_SET, position, \
           gst.SEEK_TYPE_NONE, -1)

gtk.main()
```

*I'm familiar with other programming languages than Python, so do not hesitate to answer using your favorite language... :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the debug output says:

```
0:00:00.447509530  6848      0x10d6e30 DEBUG               wavparse gstwavparse.c:1020:gst_wavparse_perform_seek:<wavparse0> negative playback rates are not supported yet.
```

so you should file a bug to request this be implemented, or implement it.